# Is it possible for a space rocket to escape a planet's gravity if the gravity was 10 times that of earth?

Tags: spacex, rockets, space-shuttle

I know that the scenario isn't realistic but lets assume that we have a planet which is identical to ours except that it's gravity is 10 times bigger. Would it be possible to launch a space rocket that can escape the gravity and go to space?

I kinda find it theoretically possible if we reduce the mass of the orbiter (keeping it relatively much smaller than the rocket boosters  ) and use big amount of fuel to launch it. However I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, it seems like a duplicate.

Comment: @ibrahimalazzawi this is a very good question! (I think so because I asked something similar) Please don't feel bad that it has been marked as duplicate, that's not a bad thing. Since there is already a good answer there, your question will help direct future readers to it. Welcome to Stack Exchange!